# Distinct não funciona

Tags: mysql

Boa tarde Pessoal, alguém sabe me dizer o por que não funciona essa query. Na verdade ela funciona, mas traz os valores de maneira errada (duplicando o campo departamento), como se distinct não funcionasse.

```
select distinct r.departamento, s.status, 
count(s.status) as quantidade from sac as s 
inner join responsaveis as r on s.id_sac = 
r.sac_id where r.departamento = 1 and s.status_sac = 1
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o retorno de dados da sua query é essa da imagem? Mas ainda assim não esta certo sua query, aparentemente, no seu caso vc deveria usar um group by ao invés do distinct por causa desse count.

Comment: Repare na imagem que o departamento duplica, e sac_id também. Eu preciso que o distinct funcione nessa tabela e não na tabela "sac"

Comment: Explique melhor os dados que deseja trazer e coloque a estrutura das duas tabelas

Answer (score 2):

O distinct agrupa linhas completamente iguais, o que não é o caso de acordo  com os resultados que foram apresentados no grid que você postou.

Como você está utilizando uma função de agrupamento (o count) o adequado seria utilizar uma cláusula "group by", agrupando pelos registros únicos que deverão ser contados, esta é a forma correta de fazer este distinct, pelo que entendi da sua consulta.

Caso minha resposta não atenda sua necessidade por favor edite sua pergunta e inclua mais informações sobre as tabelas do banco de dados e seus registros para que possa auxiliar.

Comment: Não sabia que o distinct agrupa linhas totalmente iguais. Por isso que não consigo.